# Jenkins Plugin. RootAction. index.jelly in seperate window

Tags: plugins, jenkins, jelly

i am writing a simple plugin and am forced to create a RootAction which displays a page (the index.jelly) and needs some additional values to confirm and then execute the methode.

My problem is, that the index.jelly file gets always displayed on a blank window.
But i do need it to be included inside of the Jenkinstemplate in the main table, as usual.

Can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Any ideas?

RestartJksLink.java

```
package org.jenkinsci.plugins.tomcat_app_restart;

import hudson.Extension;
import hudson.model.ManagementLink;

/**
 *
 *
 * @author [...]
 */
@Extension
public class RestartJksLink extends ManagementLink {
    @Override
    public String getIconFileName() {
        return "/plugin/tomcat-app-restart/images/restart.png";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUrlName() {
        return "jksrestart";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
       return "Restart your Jenkins-Application on Tomcat";
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "Restart Jenkins-App on Tomcat";
    }
}
```

RestartJksRootAction.java

```
package org.jenkinsci.plugins.tomcat_app_restart;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;

import jenkins.model.Jenkins;
import hudson.Extension;
import hudson.model.RootAction;
import hudson.util.FormValidation;

@Extension
public class RestartJksRootAction implements RootAction {
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "Restart Jenkins on Tomcat";
    }

    public String getIconFileName() {
        if (!Jenkins.getInstance().hasPermission(Jenkins.ADMINISTER)) {
          return null;
        }

        if (!Jenkins.getInstance().getLifecycle().canRestart()) {
          return null;
        }

        return "/plugin/tomcat-app-restart/images/restart.png";
    }

    public String getUrlName() {
        return "jksrestart";
    }

    public FormValidation doJksRestart() {
        Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication ("admin", "admin".toCharArray());
            }
        });

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8888/manager/text/start?path=/jenkins");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            System.out.println("" + connection.getResponseMessage());

            return FormValidation.ok("Success");
        } catch (IOException e) {

            return FormValidation.error("Client error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

index.jelly inside: resources.org.jenkinsci.plugins.tomcat_app_restart.RestartJksRootAction

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form" xmlns:i="jelly:fmt" xmlns:p="/lib/hudson/project">
  <f:validateButton
   title="${%Restart Jenkins}" progress="${%Restarting...}"
   method="JksRestart" with="" />
</j:jelly>
```

Thank you guys!

I am new to jenkins plugin development, this would help me a lot to understand.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

this demo (rootaction-example-plugin) helped a lot.You can read it.

https://github.com/gustavohenrique/jenkins-plugins/tree/master/rootaction-example-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Add the `<l:main-panel>` tag and the the `<l:layout norefresh="true">`tag to the index.jelly file.

And include the side panel:

- Pass the the build to Action (through a parameter of the constructor)

  - The build can be retrieved out of the parameters of the perform method which is inherited from the BuildStepCompatibilityLayer class (by Extending Publisher).
- Create a getBuild() method in the Action class
- Add the `<st:include it="${it.build}" page="sidepanel.jelly" />` tag with the build

**Jelly Example (index.jelly):**

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form" xmlns:i="jelly:fmt" xmlns:p="/lib/hudson/project">
    <l:layout norefresh="true">
        <st:include it="${it.build}" page="sidepanel.jelly" />
        <l:main-panel>
            <f:validateButton title="${%Restart Jenkins}" progress="${%Restarting...}" method="JksRestart" with="" />
        </l:main-panel>
    </l:layout>
</j:jelly>
```

**Java Action class example:**

```
package tryPublisher.tryPublisher;

import hudson.model.Action;
import hudson.model.AbstractBuild;


public class ExampleAction implements Action {
    AbstractBuild<?,?> build;

    public ExampleAction(AbstractBuild<?,?> build) {
        this.build = build;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIconFileName() {
        return "/plugin/action.png";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "ExampleAction";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUrlName() {
        return "ExampleActionUrl";
    }

    public AbstractBuild<?,?> getBuild() {
        return this.build;
    }
}
```

**Java Publisher class example:**

```
package tryPublisher.tryPublisher;

import java.io.IOException;

import hudson.Launcher;
import hudson.model.AbstractBuild;
import hudson.model.BuildListener;
import hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor;
import hudson.tasks.Publisher;

public class ExamplePublisher extends Publisher {

    @Override
    public BuildStepMonitor getRequiredMonitorService() {
        return BuildStepMonitor.NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean perform(AbstractBuild<?, ?> build, Launcher launcher,
            BuildListener listener) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        build.getActions().add(new ExampleAction(build));

        return true;
    }

}
```

The .jelly file has to be in the right resources map of the plugin project. In a map with the same name as the name of the Java class implementing Action. The name of the .jelly is important also.